# Freeze First Column of Sharepoint List view

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

i want to fix first column (ex: Title column) of my sharepoint list view, so that whenever the user scroll horizontally the first column should be fixed.

Thanks in advance for your support.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF8R7.png)

Comment: I support you. Without showing things like a question (displayed with '?') or what you have tried such as code or details of attempts, you unfortunately will not get more than that.

Answer (score 0):

[Daniel](http://spoodoo.com/downloads/) shared a solution for this requirement.

[stickyHeaders_3.2.0.js](http://spoodoo.com/download/javascripts/stickyheaders/stickyHeaders_3.2.0.js)